# Remove website Top Navigation Bar in a WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to show a website through a WKWebView.
My problem is that I don't want to show the navigationBar of the WebSite.
It looks like I have to use webview.evaluateJavaScript but is there an other way of doing it. If NO, can you provide an example with webview.evaluateJavaScript

Thanks

Comment: Have you got solution for this problem. In my app there are two navigation bars 1. UINavigationController navigation bar and 2. Web page which is loaded in webview. I want to hide UINavigationController navigation bar

Answer (score -1):

Looking a bit online, I found that on the particular website you can check for navigator.userAgent.

Then I could use the following that helped me remove the content that I want

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { [weak webView] (result, error) in
            if let webView = webView, let userAgent = result as? String {
                webView.customUserAgent = userAgent + "/_app_"

            }
    }
```

Comment: The user wants to remove the website header i.e the navigation bar/logo/menu. Please read questions carefully before answering